# make: *** [src/Class.o] Error 1 eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

ok so i installed CDT for C++ development on my machine. I tried to make it work and followed these [instructions](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html) to set everything up. By mistake i have gone into the `Project>Properties>C++ Build>Enviorement` and hit restore defaults by mistake. I dont know if that changed anything but i get the following error when i run my class.

I tried to switch the slashes in the given path "C:\Users\Nathan\workspace\Project\Debug" to forward slashes but that did nothing. I still get the same error. Any hints on what im doing wrong?

```
19:12:58 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Project ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/Project.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Project.d" -MT"src/Project.d" -o "src/Project.o" "../src/Project.cpp"
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:\Users\Nathan\workspace\Project\Debug
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Users/Nathan/workspace/Project/Debug
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/cwchar:44:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/iosfwd:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/ios:39,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/iostream:40,
                 from ../src/Project.cpp:9:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/cstddef:44:20: fatal error: stddef.h: No such file or directory
src/subdir.mk:18: recipe for target `src/Project.o' failed
compilation terminated.
make: *** [src/Project.o] Error 1

19:12:59 Build Finished (took 535ms)
```

Comment: It's saying `stddef.h` doesn't exist on your machine.  Does it?

Comment: yea its not there. I just dont understand why. ANd how can i fix that?

Comment: Figure out which Cygwin package contains it and install it I guess.

Comment: I cant find where it located I tried looking online but most of the people that have problems like this are on linux. I also installed most of the development stuff from Cygwin (except some big files which didnt mention C++ or g++ etc) i dont think it was in one of those files. At least i hope not.

Comment: http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=stddef%5C.h

Comment: I already installed those directories, but i tried re-installing and it fixed my problem but now im getting a have a different issue that the build completes successfully but when i try to lunch the program the lunch fails claiming no binaries are found.